# Oculus SDK: Unable to run Oculus Tiny Room using OpenGL

Tags: opengl, oculus

I am getting started with Oculus SDK. As a first step, I decided to try out the "OculusRoomTiny (GL)" example from the provided samples. The project compiles all right on Visual Studio 2017. However, when I run the binary, I get the following error

> OpenGL supports only the default graphics adapter.

I am using a Windows 10 desktop with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700k CPU @ 4.00GHz and a dedicated NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti GPU.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Update NVIDIA drivers
2. Go to Nvidia Control Panel --> Manage 3D settings --> OpenGL Rendering GPU and change that from "Auto" to "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
3. Change BIOS to set the dedicated GPU as the primary GPU
4. Disable multi-monitor support in BIOS

None of have provided any positive results.

I have already looked at all the online posts I could find and haven't been able to find a solution in a couple of days. So any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The error was caused because the Oculus was plugged into the dedicated GPU and the monitor for the desktop was plugged into the on-chip Intel GPU. It was resolved when I plugged both of them into the NVIDIA GPU.